# How to call custom Module/Model class in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I have to call custom Module class in billing.phtml which shows extra field on checkout page.

But I am getting `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object`

**Below is my code -**

File Name - Business.php

File Path - `/var/www/html/app/code/community/Partsimple/CustomFields/Model/Primarybusiness`

```
class Partsimple_CustomFields_Model_Primarybusiness_Business extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {


           $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => '',
                    'label' => 'Please Select Primary Business'
            );
            $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => 1,
                    'label' => 'End Consumer / DIY'
            );
            $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => 2,
                    'label' => 'Service Technician'
            );
            $this->_options[] = array(
                    'value' => 3,
                    'label' => 'Other Professional'
            );

         //   $this->_options = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/region_collection')->load()->toOptionArray();

        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

**File Name - **config.xml****

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Partsimple_CustomFields>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Partsimple_CustomFields>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Partsimple_CustomFields>
                <class>Partsimple_CustomFields_Model</class>
            </Partsimple_CustomFields>
        </models>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
            <vendor_account>
                <create>1</create>
                <update>1</update>
            </vendor_account>
            </customer_account>
            <customer_address>
            <vendor_account>
                <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
            </vendor_account>
            <primary_business>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
            <primary_business>
            </customer_address>
            <sales_convert_order_address>
            <vendor_account>
                <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                </vendor_account>
            </sales_convert_order_address>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <vendor_account>
                    <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                    <to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address>
                </vendor_account>
                <primary_business>
                    <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                    <to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address>
                </primary_business>
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>   
</config>
```

And I am writing below line in **billing.phtml** file to call above `business.php` class method `getAlloptions();`

```
<?php  echo Mage::getModel('partsimple/customFields_model_primarybusiness_business')->getAllOptions();?>
```

I have also tried to print class

```
<?php  echo "Class: ".get_class(Mage::getModel('partsimple/customfields_model_primarybusiness_business'));?>
```

But I am getting nothing. 
Please let me know where I am doing wrong, 
I want to call this method on billing.phtml.

## **Updates**

After making the correction in config.xml file its working fine.

> To check errors in `config.xml` open this file in browser after editing in > any editor so it will show error.

Now The attribute is showing checkout page and admin customer page and customer my account  section but in this section. I am not able to update it. Which fields needs to be added in config.xml fot customer_account tags.

I have added like this in config.xml

```
<customer_account>
   <primary_business>
       <create>1</create>
         <update>1</update>
   </primary_business>
</customer_account>
```

Comment: Surely you want: `Mage::getModel('partsimple_customFields/primarybusiness_business')`

Comment: Yes, I want to echo that class method array

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this file in app/etc/modules named Partsimple_CustomFields.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<config>
    <modules>
        <Partsimple_CustomFields>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Partsimple_CustomFields>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Yes I have added this xml.

Comment: I tried to print <?php  echo "Class: ".get_class(Mage::getModel('partsimple/customfields_model_primarybusiness_business'));?> But still not getting my class. I think class is not instantiated Can you tell how can I instantiated this class.

Comment: You try to do a "getAllOptions()" on something, could you try an echo, die, var_dump or similar on this "something" and tell me about ?

Comment: Yes I tried to echo this method. But I am getting  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object

Comment: I think the issue is you have nothing while doing : echo "Class: ".get_class(Mage::getModel('partsimple/customfields_model_primarybusiness_business'));
As it is empty, you "call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object"

The question is : why is this class empty ?

Comment: so what should be solution on that. Method is not empty, It  has array

Answer (score 0):

You have said magento that your models will be called with "Partsimple_CustomFields" in the config.xml, so you should always call your models using the name "Partsimple_CustomFields" as below:

```
<?php  echo Mage::getModel('Partsimple_CustomFields/primarybusiness_business')->getAllOptions();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at your `<models>` node. You have your models grouped as Partsimple_CustomFields but you are trying to instantiate your class with this `Mage::getModel('partsimple/customFields_model_primarybusiness_business')`. You need to either change the first node in the models node like shown below

```
    <models>
        <partsimple>
            <class>Partsimple_CustomFields_Model</class>
        </partsimple>
    </models>
```

OR you need to instantiate your model like this:

```
Mage::getModel('Partsimple_CustomFields/customfields_model_primarybusiness_business')
```

That first node inside of `<models>, <blocks>, and <helpers>` is your your grouping node. When Magento tried to determine what class your are intending to instantiate, `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName($groupType, $classId, $groupRootNode)` is called upon to turn Partsimple_CustomFields/customfields_model_primarybusiness_business into an actual class name. It checks your config.xml.

I should also mention that is common practice not to use any capital letters at all within your model, blocks, and helpers nodes.